# Back button should take to parent route

Tags: angularjs, cordova, back-button

I am making an angularjs  app using cordova but the problem is when I press back button it traces back the path I have followed. 
ex. I have made a homepage then a session homepage and inside session homepage there are session1, sesion2......session5etc. 
Now the problem is if I move from homepage to session homepage and then to session1 and after that session2 then on pressing back button it will goto session1 instead of going to session homepage.
How to get rid of it, should I make some directive or is there any other method

Comment: Are you using the angular router or some different mechanism? Maybe you should edit your question to show us what you've tried there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a "back" button. Back button is what it says - to go back to the previous page.

If you wish to go to a specific page, then you need to explicitly specify the link to that page. You cannot call that as going "back" - you intend to go to a specific page.

```
<a href="/#/main-session-page">Back to session page</a>
```